Does higher speed increase the cornering radius for a given steering angle
If slip angle increases with increase in cornering force does that mean I have to steer more to have the same cornering radius under higher load( higher mass or higher cornering speed).
Here is how I thought of it,suppose the tires have infinite grip with the ground.Now consider two cases of a car going around the same corner radius where in one case there is more cornering force due to higher load than the other case, shouldn't I steer more due to the fact that higher cornering force is accompanied with higher slip angle and the only way for higher slip angle to be achieved is by steering more since by definition of slip angle and given that the direction of travel is the same then the direction which the wheels point must be different and hence the steering angle.
But there is a problem I searched online and it says that the cornering speed doesn't matter.Also another problem is the concept of turning radius doesn't make sense because the speed at which the turn is done isn't mentioned.
So where did my reasoning go wrong?

If you have infinite grip, then you can have turning radius of zero. I think your description of your question is quite confused and you should reword everything to make it simpler for us to see if you understood what it is you are trying to discuss.

What I meant by infinite grip is the tires would never skid so one doesn't bring that up

Which of my question you didn't get and I would happily reword it.

@Johngreg your entire middle paragraph is a single sentence with marginal punctuation. That's a a little hard to parse for most of us.

either way, if we assume that our vehicle does not skid and that the wheels remain on the ground, turn radius is effectively only depends on the size of the vehicle as well as its steering. A longer vehicle has a larger turn radius, a vehicle where both front and rear wheels can steer has a smaller one, etc.

@paulina but how. As I said in my question a higher slip angle is required for a higher cornering force but considering a moment in time where two cars with different cornering force, the only way they would acheive the same turning radius at different loads is by steering more. That is unless my reasoning is wrong

@paulina is correct but she is referring to something called Ackerman angle, which is a different topic.  Your question is more about tire dynamics.

I'm not going to use the term "slip" because cornering on rubber tires is a little complicated.  A good intuitive explanation is here.
https://www.yourdatadriven.com/tyre-slip-angle-explained/
A more technical, but also good answer is here
Why does a tire produce more traction when sliding slightly?
To answer your question, assuming no skidding, cornering FORCE is a function of slip angle. The force REQUIRED to follow a given radial path with no skidding is a function of velocity AND radius.  So velocity is relevant but I think it's mostly a matter of which variables you assume are independent vs dependent.
[edited to use the term "skidding" instead of "sliding"]

So for higher velocity and same cornering radius I need more steering angle?

Yes. All else being equal, the force required for a mass to travel on a circular path is equal to (mass * velocity^2 / radius) directed towards the center of the circle.
